# How to select option in jQuery using text of option tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to select a certain option in a select box, but it's not working:

```
var category = $(row + 'td:nth-child(4)').text();
$('#category_id', theCloned).load('/webadmin/video/get_categories',function(){
   $('#category_id', theCloned).val(category);
});
```

There's no error thrown, but it doesn't change the select box.  What am I doing wrong here?

Here is an example of the options loaded by the load() call:

```
<option value="1">Capabilities</option>
<option value="2">Application Focus</option>
<option value="5">Fun</option>
```

The value of the category variable is "Fun" or "Capabilities", etc.

Comment: Would you post the html code of the select box, please?  It will greatly help our ability to help you.

Comment: and you're sure `category` matches the value you're targeting exactly? try to `alert(category)` and inspect the value to be sure.f

Comment: I have tried using alert to double-check everything, and it all matches up....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var $selectbox = $('#category_id', theCloned), // cache the element to avoid lookup overheads
    category = $(row + 'td:nth-child(4)').text();
$selectbox.load('/webadmin/video/get_categories', function(){
   $selectbox
    .find('option')
    .filter(function(){
        return $(this).text() === category;
    })
    .prop('selected', true);
});
```

---

#### Update 1

Updated the code to adjust to the code you presented in your update. This will work. However if an option will contain a part of the string and not the full string it will still be part of the selected elements. E.g.
If the options will be

```
<option value="1">Capabilities</option>
<option value="2">Application Focus</option>
<option value="5">Fun</option>
<option value="6">Fun Time</option>
<option value="6">Funhouse</option>
```

And the `category` variable will have the value `Fun`, all three last options will be part of the selector.

---

#### Update 2

Changed the code to filter the options whose text fully matches the value of the `category` variable. Thus, you won't have to worry about the Update 1 above.

Comment: Your code works, but why does the code to exactly match the entire option text not work?  That would be better, since I can't guarantee that I'll never have partial strings in the option list (as in your example).

Comment: @croceldon: Because that's how the `:contains` selector works. Give me a few secs to make it better... Update: I changed the code. Test if that works for full string match.

Comment: Actually, I meant why didn't my original code work...but it doesn't matter, because your updated example works fine.  Nice work!

Comment: @croceldon: Your original code didn't work because you were trying to set the value of the selectbox, but the variable `category` does not hold the value, it holds the text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#category_id', theCloned).val($.trim(category));
```

Comment: This does not work.  The selected index of the of the select box is not being changed.

Comment: What is the value in `category`? Are you sure any `option` with that value is there in the select box?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#id_of_select_box').val('your_value');
```

this will do

Answer (score 0):

At last i found a new solution [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f66hteoL/)

```
<select>

    <option value='1'>one</option>
    <option value='2' >two</option>
    <option value='3' >three</option>
</select>
```

**Script**

```
$("select").on("change",function(){    
    alert($("select option:selected").text());
});
```